# Does "somebody of my caliber" mean the speaker themselves?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

I was watching a game video on Youtube, and I was not sure the meaning "somebody of my caliber" when Loretta blamed Jonathan for his rudeness.
Here are the quotes.

> (a mysterious vampire woman appears in front of them)
>
> Charlotte: I knew I smelled something. Seems like some maggots got
>   inside.
>
> Jonathan: !! A vampire!
>
> Loretta: My, My, such attitude... **You dare disrespect somebody of
>   my caliber?**
>
> Loretta: I am a LADY. Lady Loretta. As you said, your battle just
>   now may have weakened us a bit... However, I do have some
>   tragic news for you. This wasn't the only one of my father's
>   paintings.

I have looked it up into some online dictionary webs but there are no example sentences for "somebody of my caliber".

Since Loretta said that to Jonathan, I guess that "**You dare disrespect somebody of
my caliber**" is an insinuation, which means "You dare disrespect me"
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Its meaning should be obvious if you look up the word *caliber* in a dictionary. BTW, the dialogue sounds like Japanese to me, even though it's in English. Being curious, I checked and found its Wikipedia page [Castlevania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castlevania) (キャッスルヴァニア). I guess that in Japanese it would be something like "You dare disrespect someone of the level (of quality/ability/intelligence) as high as me?", so I think you're right about it being an insinuation.

Comment: It was my pleasure!

Comment: "*someone* of my caliber" is also commonly used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in guessing it is an **insinuation**. It means that the speaker feels they are superior to the listener (and possibly the general public as well) with either **higher morals** or **greater abilities** and is being disrespected by the **inferior** listener.  It is usually said with a level of **disdain** and **contempt** to the listener.

A colloquialism which gets used is :

> Seller: I'm sorry but you'll have to wait your turn.
>   Buyer: **Do you know who I am?** (*emphatically and with disdain*)

meaning **don't you know how important I am?** No one else matters, you should be paying attention to me.

Comment: Pleasure @Kitty, keep asking questions!  (and please tick the answer if you like it)